# PHP: looping an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

Sorry if this is too obvious but I’ve been too long on it and now I cannot think how to do it.

I have:

```
$objectPerson = new Person();
$objectPerson->setName($arrayName);
$objectPerson->setLastName($arrayLastName);
$arrayPerson = array();  
$arrayPerson[] = $objectPerson;
$objectMainClass->setArrayPerson($arrayPerson);
```

`$arrayName` and `$arrayLastName` are coming from a `$_REQUEST` and have two elements each: John, Jean and Smith, Taylor

I will store `$objectMainClass`  later  in my database table that has this structure:

```
Id | Name | LastName
```

But the way the code is now, I’m storing John, Jean in the name field and Smith, Taylor in the last name field like that:

```
Id | Name       | LastName
-------------------------------
1  | John, Jean | Smith, Taylor
```

What can I do to get:

```
Id | Name | LastName
--------------------
1  | John | Smith
2  | Jean | Taylor
```

??

I know I have to use a foreach in the code above but I’m so stuck that I cannot think on how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fix some errors in the code, but this should work:

```
$arrayName = 'john,joe';
$arrayLastName = 'Smith,Shmoe';


$names = explode(",",   $arrayName);
$lastNames = explode(",", $arrayLastName);

$arrayPerson = array();  
//  I don't know how the actual array and object is used in your
// application, but based on context, I added your functionality
for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++)
{
    // assuming $names and $lastNames are the same length
    $name = $names[$i];
    $lastName = $lastNames[$i];

    // act on $name and $lastname however you want
    $objectPerson = new Person();
    $objectPerson->setName($name);
    $objectPerson->setLastName($lastName);
    array_push($arrayPerson, $objectPerson);
}

$objectMainClass->setArrayPerson($arrayPerson);
```

Answer (score -1):

Foreach($object as $key=>$value) {